# Delphi SetMapMode Inverts Text

Tags: delphi, winapi, graphics, textout

I am working on a graphics application and have a number of objects with captions. To put the captions, I calculate an X, Y coordinate and call:

`Canvas.TextOut(XText, YText, FCaption);`

I decided to use a different mapping mode to make conversions from world space to device space simpler:

```
SetGraphicsMode(cnv.Handle, GM_ADVANCED);
SetMapMode(pbxMain.Canvas.Handle, MM_HIENGLISH);
```

and now my captions are printing upside down, but still left to right.

Any thoughts on how to remedy that?

One approach I had considered was setting the map mode back to the default for outputting text, which would require some conversions to get X, Y in the different mode. Is that a reasonable tactic? Is it "correct" to change map mode during paint routines...?

Comment: Y axis is reversed with MM_HIENGLISH in contrast to MM_TEXT but you shouldn't get upside down text. Is it possible that you're calling SetWorldTransform at some point?

Comment: I do call SetWorldTransform for a "zoom" function.

Comment: Ok, make sure you don't have a negative eM22 of the XFORM. Otherwise please try to produce a minimal reproduction case.

Comment: I have that value set to Cos(Angle) where Angle is in radians. For an angle of 0, Cos returns +1, so that isn't it.  Hmmmmmm......I'll work up a test case.

Comment: OK! Problem solved. The issue was that I had a function for setting zoom, rotation and translation. In that function it set the mode MM_ANISOTROPIC. However, my paint handler had already set it to MM_HIENGLISH. I suspect the subsequent call to SetMapMode was somehow involved.

Your pointers led to the solution. Please post an answer of some kind here so I can check it.  :)

Comment: Glad you've resolved your issue. I posted my recommendations as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the y axis reversed when you set `MM_HIENGLISH` map mode, assuming a default previous value of `MM_TEXT`, it doesn't cause text to be output upside-down - it just effects where it's output.

You might want to check if you're calling `SetWorldTransform` which is a probable cause for the problem you observe - a faulty transformation. A negative value in `eM22` of the transformation structure parameter causes a reflection in the y axis.

Regarding the last part, I don't see any problem switching map modes during a single drawing task, apart from it might complicate maintaining the code.